# Unable to sign up at Heroku

Tags: heroku

I am unable to create an account at Heroku.com for some reason. Note that I do not have an account and am trying to create one.

I am able to click "Sign Up" on the home page, input my email address, receive the validation email, follow the link from validation email to page where input password and then am supposed to click "Save". At this screen, my email address has already been filled out (since I followed the link from the email) so I just pick a password, and put the same password in the "Confirm Password" box.

At this point I would expect the "Save" button to light up (or allow me to click it) but nothing happens when I click it.

I would check the Heroku site for help but am required to log in before getting help.

Using Chrome on Win 7. Using Lastpass for password management.

Comment: Are you entering a password of 6 characters or more, using a combination of special characters and ensuring both password and password confirmation are the same?  I just created a new account and it worked fine. If all the above is good, perhaps see if there is a newer version of Chrome available?

Comment: @JR0cket I was meeting the requirements, just realized today that Heroku wasn't smart enough to recognize when I used Lastpass to generate a password for me and fill it in. It worked when I just typed the generated password in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku requires that the password be *typed* in rather than automatically added with something like Lastpass. Once the password has been typed in, the "Save" button will light up and allow you to proceed.